# Что выполняет данное выражание в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Работая с одним open source проектом, столкнулся со строками, которые не понимаю.

```js
function MultiPeers(connection) {
  var self = this;
  var skipPeers = ['getAllParticipants', 'getLength', 'selectFirst', 'streams', 'send', 'forEach'];
  connection.peersBackup = {};
  connection.peers = {
    getLength: function() {
        var numberOfPeers = 0;
        for (var peer in this) {
          if (skipPeers.indexOf(peer) == -1) {
            numberOfPeers++;
          }
        }
        return numberOfPeers;
      }
      ..........
```

Что означает пройтись по this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пройтись по всем полям текущего объекта (в данном случае `MultiPeers.connection.peers`) и получить их имена

```js
function MultiPeers(connection) {
  var self = this;
  var skipPeers = ['getAllParticipants', 'getLength', 'selectFirst', 'streams', 'send', 'forEach'];
  connection.peersBackup = {};
  connection.peers = {
    getLength: function() {
      var numberOfPeers = 0;
      for (var peer in this) {
        console.log(peer);
        if (skipPeers.indexOf(peer) == -1) {
          numberOfPeers++;
        }
      }
      return numberOfPeers;
    }
  }
}

const con = {};
const mp = new MultiPeers(con);
con.peers.getLength();
```